# university press specialized in math books

Tags: books

I am thinking of writing a book for graduate students, on graph theory.

Apart from AMS book, does someone of you could suggest a university press that acccept submission on these arguments.

I googled a while without fortune. Does someone had some experience to share?

Thank in advance for your help.

Piero

Answer (score 7):

At this point, I think that the three publishers that publish the greatest number of graduate level textbooks in mathematics are the AMS (as you already noted), Springer-Verlag, and Cambridge University Press. If you attend the joint math meeting sometime (next JMM is in Seattle in January 2016), all three will have acquisitions editors at their book displays. So you can stop by and ask to make an appointment to speak to an acquisitions editor. The current acquisitions editors for the AMS are Eriko Hironaka in the United States and Ina Mette in Europe.